# Pdf of the minimum of two normal variables.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$, $Y$ be two normal, independent variables with zero mean. What is the distribution of $\min(X,Y)$?

Comment: What have you tried to do so far?

Answer (score 3):

$P(\mathrm{min}(X,Y)\leq x) = 1-P(\mathrm{min}(X,Y) > x) = 1-P(X>x\cap Y>x)=1-P(X>x)P(Y>x)=1-(1-F_X(x))(1-F_Y(x))$

where the $F_X(x)$ is the cumulative of $X$, and the same for $Y$. If they have the same variance the last two factors will be the same, simplifying the expression.

You can fill in with the correct expressions for the cumulatives and maybe you can recognize it as a familiar distribution but i doubt it.